# VBA to remove everything after 5 spaces

Tags: excel, vba

Have this VBA code which removes eveything after first space

Trying to modify it so it removes eveything after 5 spaces instead in the whole of sheet1 cells or post results into sheet 2 either way is ok

for example

from

It was a good day today but a little cold

to

It was a good day today

```
Sub Test()
 Dim X As Long, Uniques() As String, Obj As Object
 Dim Data As Variant, Results As Variant, ObjKeys() As String
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Data = Range("H2", Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Value
 For X = 1 To UBound(Data)
   Data(X, 1) = Left(Data(X, 1), InStr(Data(X, 1) & " ", " ") - 1)
 Next
 Set Obj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For X = 1 To UBound(Data)
     Obj.Item(CStr(Data(X, 1))) = 1 ' CStr(Data(X, 1))
   Next
   ObjKeys = Split(Join(Obj.keys))
   ReDim Results(1 To UBound(ObjKeys) + 1, 1 To 1)
   For X = 0 To UBound(ObjKeys)
     Results(X + 1, 1) = ObjKeys(X)
   Next
   Range("H2").Resize(UBound(Data)) = Data
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J1").Value = Range("H1").Value
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J2").Resize(UBound(Results)) = Results
 End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Would really help your question if you post some example values.  It's not clear if you mean a run of 5 spaces together, or 5 spaces with other content between them.

Comment: 5 spaces with other content between them

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```vb
Const NUM_SPACES As Long = 5
Dim s As String, arr

s = "It was a good day today but a little cold"

arr = Split(s, " ", NUM_SPACES + 2)   'split to max 7 elements

'remove anything in the last position (arr starts at zero)
If UBound(arr) = NUM_SPACES + 1 Then arr(NUM_SPACES + 1) = ""  

Debug.Print Join(arr, " ") '> It was a good day today
```

Comment: You didn't get rid of the trailing delimiter (space). Maybe `... Then ReDim Preserve arr(0 To NUM_SPACES)` is a good idea.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - good point, or `Debug.Print Trim(Join(arr, " "))`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution which does not require VBA:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",100)),500))
```

[image]

This replaces each space with 100 spaces.
Takes the first 500 (5*100 spaces) characters.
Then removes all the additional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 with the latest functions, simply:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1," ",6)
```

*Will return an error if there are not enough delimiters. You may want to specify what to happen if that is a possibility.*

[image]

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

*Again, since you did not specify what you want if there are not five spaces, this routine returns the entire string if there are fewer than five spaces*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],

//create list of column headers
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),

//set all data types to text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(colNames, each {_, type text})),

//Remove all after the fifth space (including that space)
    #"Trim Strings" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", 
        List.Transform(colNames, (cn)=> {cn, each try Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Text.Split(_," "),5)," ") otherwise null}))

in
    #"Trim Strings"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks there are 50000 rows and 1200 columns so I need VBA solution

Comment: @yend84 I edited my answer to provide a Power Query solution, available in Excel 2010+.  As written, it should adapt automatically to your data table.

Comment: thanks ron this does work in power query however takes 30 mins to complete

Comment: @yend84 Try Ted Williams method using VBA and arrays.